# Model theoretic translation of Hilbert's Basis Theorem

Tags: logic, commutative-algebra, model-theory

[A few interesting comments to [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172768/) made me understand that I need to address some more fundamental facts. (The standard literature is elusive.)]

> What (if any) is the correct way to translate Hilbert's Basis Theorem into logic / model theory?

Hilbert Basis Theorem comes in two forms.

The modern form

> If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, and $x$ is a single variable, then $R[x]$ is a Noetherian ring.

The original(?) form

> If $F$ is a field and $x$ is a tuple of variables, then $F[x]$ is a Noetherian ring.

This second form sounds nearer to logic / model theory.

Still, it is a slippery terrain....

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  What is the purpose of this "translation"?

Comment: That certainly isn't the original form: Noether was aged 8 in 1890, when Hilbert published his  proof of the theorem. PS: like @EricWofsey I find it very unclear what you asking about. Your first form is just what drops out by analysing the inductive hypotheses for an inductive proof of your second form.

Comment: @RobArthan Hilbert did not say *Noetherian*, but this is what he had in mind. Soon I'll try to clarify the question.